# Align items on profile preferences page

Tags: feature-request, design, preferences

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current

> [image]

Right now `input` has style:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(.s-checkbox), input[type="radio"]:not(.s-radio) {
    border: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

So, you could just set `margin` to `3px`.

> [image]